# Ionic cordova build error with platforms errors [[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.]

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

This is the error even after removing and adding the android platform to build the ionic cordova app

92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Venkata Sai Teja\Ionic\Abmiro-Customer\subscription-app\platforms\android\platform_www\cordova.js'

Comment: Try to delete node_modules, then run npm install. Also invalidate and clear cache in the IDE. After you do that, try again to build a new Android application.

Comment: Clear cache and deleted node modules. But, still getting same error